# Yii2 page title other than inherit controller from another class tha controller

Tags: php, inheritance, yii2

In my [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) controller's action, the page title may be set as follows:

```
$this->view->title .= ' | Some title';
```

The problem here, it is not seem to have a default title for the whole of the application. i.e My site name | the page title.

The only way that I, currently, know to work is to make another controller class inherited from the `controller` class and the define or set `$this->view->title`  define it in the construction method, then inherit all of my controllers from this class like the following:

```
namespace common\controllers
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class MainController extends Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
     $this->view->title = 'My site name ';
   }
}
```

Then in any controller I should extend from `MainController`.

**The question is:**

Is there any configuration way or bootstrap way to set a default value for the page title, then I can concatenate another value to it through the action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply handle this in your layout :

```
<title>My site name | <?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
```

And after in your view, you just have to set the title like this :

```
$this->title = 'Some title';
```

Or you could also set the application name in your config

```
$config = [
    'name' => 'My site name',
    ...
];
```

And use it in your layout :

```
<title><?= Yii::$app->name ?> | <?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, Where did my brain?! :) Thank you very much! However, if there a way to read it from a configuration in the layout, I will be appreciated. i.e setting the site name as a configuration entry then read it in the view.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm so appreciated.